# How does C# compiler remove Debug.Assert's in release builds?

Tags: c#, debugging, assert

I was recently going through some code and considering whether I need to be careful with the expressions placed inside `Debug.Assert` statements, such as expensive operations or those with side effects.  However, it appears the compiler is pretty smart about completely removing the `Assert` statement and inner expressions.

For example, the following will only print on debug builds:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.Assert(SideEffect());
}
private static bool SideEffect()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Side effect!");
    return true;
}
```

And this will complain that `o` is being used before initialization on release builds:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object o;
    Debug.Assert(Initialize(out o));
    o.ToString();
}
private static bool Initialize(out object o)
{
    o = new object();
    return true;
}
```

It even seems to stand up to expressions such as this (printing "After" in both cases):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (false) Debug.Assert(true);
    Console.WriteLine("After");
}
```

I was a little suprised with how smart the compiler is here and its ability to correctly detect cases when the `Debug.Assert` is removed.  So, it got me curious..

- How exactly is the statement removed?  The expression tree must be built before the statement is removed in order to properly execute the above `if` statement correctly.
- Is the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class special here, or is it possible to build your own methods with similar handling?
- Are there any ways to "trick" the preprocessor here?  Even better, are there situations that one might encounter in real-world code where this could be problematic?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx for some thoughts on this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Debug.Assert` is declared with [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx); as the documentation states, this "[i]ndicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined."

The C# compiler has specific support for that attribute and removes the Debug.Assert during release builds, so it is never part of the built expression tree.

If you right-click on one of your `Debug.Assert` statements, you should be able to go to the definition.  Visual Studio will show you "code" generated from the metadata, and there you can see the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute applied.  So this code is only respected when `DEBUG` is `#define`'d as part of your build.

Answer (score 5):

The methods on the debugger use the pseudo-custom attribute, [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx), which the compiler detects and removes any calls to any methods with that attribute unless the specified compilation symbol (in this case, `DEBUG`) is defined. Anyone may use the attribute on `void` methods without any `out` parameters.

Comment: It should be stressed that it removes calls ***where no matching symbol is defined*** - it can be any symbol, not just DEBUG. Also, `out` parameters are disallowed.

Comment: The MSDN documentation states: "Compilers that comply with the Common Language Specification (CLS) are permitted to ignore ConditionalAttribute. The C#, J#, and Visual Basic compilers support ConditionalAttribute". Does this mean that the C# compiler of Visual Studio does not comply with CLS ? - the remark is cryptic to me.

Comment: No, it just means that CLS-compliant compilers don't have to support the ConditionalAttribute, so it's optional. C# complies with the CLS.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that Debug.Assert is special in any way; it's just using the `Conditional` attribute so that the compiler removes it when it detects that the 'preprocessor' define does not exist (C# does not have a preprocessor!).

You can use it like so to do the same thing (so long as you've defined `DEBUG` (or whatever symbol you want to switch on, `TRACE` is another popular one):

```
[Conditional("DEBUG"), Conditional("TRACE")]
public void DebugOnlyMethod() {
    Console.WriteLine("Won't see me unless DEBUG or TRACE is defined");
}
```

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the `Debug` class was the original motivation behind `ConditionalAttribute` back in the day.

Comment: @Matt Greer: most likely, they appear to be the only Framework classes that use it.