# Checking arguments only in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, arguments, assert

I have a class Vector3 with constructor:

```
    public Vector3 (double x, double y, double z)
    {
        #if DEBUG
            if (double.IsNan (x)) throw something...       
        #endif

        X = x;
        ...
    }
```

I don't wanna check for NaN in release mode. So, is it a good practice to add checking only for debug mode? I have said in XML comments constructor does not check for Nan or infinity. But I can check in debug mode for better denuging right? Is this OK? Or bad pattern?

Comment: Why would you do this exactly? What's the added value?

Comment: Dont understand your question? I want to instantiate vector3 struct as fast i can. So  I do not check for Nan or Infinity. But in debug mode, why not? Is this ok?

Comment: I think it is completely valid to make this check, but for other reasons (the time factor is negligible). There are situations you think that a situation should not Happen, but if it does you don't want to throw an error. On the other side, on develop time you would want to get a notification that this situation has occurred. as mentioned in answers below `Debug.Assert` is the correct way to go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(!double.IsNan(x), "Some message shown if assert fails".)
```

It is ignored when compiling in Release mode, so there is no impact on performance (unless you're in Debug mode of course).

Comment: AlexD said it will do just a call to a method in Release mode. So: will it be ignored in release mode or not?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750482/how-does-c-sharp-compiler-remove-debug-asserts-in-release-builds

Comment: Yes, sorry for not replying earlier but you found more info yourself :)